# Array detects only a part from an input word instead of the entire word

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I have a problem in my Android app, it's an app using voice recognition, and Google TTS. It's like a SIRI client. As you can see here when the user says a word given in the array:

```
String[] g = { "hallo", "heey", "hoi", "hey", "he", "hee", "hay" };
for (String strings : g) {
    if (mostLikelyThingHeard.contains(strings)) {
        String[] array = { "leuk dat je er bent", "heeyy" };
        String randomStr = array[new Random()
                .nextInt(array.length)];
        tts.speak(randomStr, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        return;
    }
}
String[] f = { "haha", "hah", "ha" };
for (String strings : f) {
    if (mostLikelyThingHeard.contains(strings)) {
        String[] array = { "haha leuk grapje", "hiehaho" };
        String randomStr = array[new Random()
                .nextInt(array.length)];
        tts.speak(randomStr, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        return;
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine but when the user says "hallo" it detects the first two characters "ha" first. Which is mentioned in String array 'f'. So this is annoying, the whole word isn't detected but only a part from it.

When I swap the two string arrays like this:

```
String[] f = { "haha", "hah", "ha" };
for (String strings : f) {
    if (mostLikelyThingHeard.contains(strings)) {
        String[] array = { "haha leuk grapje", "hiehaho" };
        String randomStr = array[new Random()
                .nextInt(array.length)];
        tts.speak(randomStr, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        return;
    }
}
    String[] g = { "hallo", "heey", "hoi", "hey", "he", "hee",
        "hay" };
for (String strings : g) {
    if (mostLikelyThingHeard.contains(strings)) {
        String[] array = { "leuk dat je er bent", "heeyy" };
        String randomStr = array[new Random()
                .nextInt(array.length)];
        tts.speak(randomStr, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        return;
    }
}
```

Then it does detect "hallo" first instead of "ha"

But if I make more than 100 arrays this would be annoying, so how can I let java use the best matching word from a array instead of just a part?

I know it's hard to understand but if you guys don't understand it see my source here:
http://github.com/gi097/PWS

EDIT:

When I change

```
contains
```

to

```
equals
```

I fix this problem but now I got a new one:

If I create an array like:

```
"I am"
```

When the user says: "I am Giovanni" we have the problem that "I am" isn't detected anymore due the equals....

EDIT2

It can be fixed I think with splitting mostLikelythingHeard "I am Giovanni" to "I" "am" "Giovanni" but how?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
mostLikelyThingHeard.contains(strings)
```

Use:

```
Arrays.sort(g);
int index = Arrays.binarySearch(g, mostLikelyThingHeard);
if (index >= 0) {
    System.out.println("I heard it properly and its ", g[index]);
}
```

Contains check for subsequence of String as mentioned [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29). So if your string was "hallo", then `"Hallo".contains("ha")` searches for ha within hallo and yes ha is within hallo and hence your issue.

Comment: I don't know if this will work, if I have for example 100 arrays, will it detect an entire word instead of a part characters?

Comment: Yes it will compare entire word. So if your string was hallo and you had ha and hallo in your array, it will find hallo and not ha. Try it out.

Comment: Okay will try when I´m home :D

Comment: I managed it by changing contains to equals. But now another problem is that every sentence has to be totally the same

Comment: what do you mean by sentence has to be same?

Comment: See the answer that I made: I hope you understand the problem with "equals". On the other hand I didn't get your code properly in the IDE @almasshaikh

Comment: he wrote it as an answer :(

Comment: So maybe you guys know howto split mostLikelythingHeard? Mentioned in edit2?